# Generating random numbers in a range (0-4) with the constraint that each number can only be generated a certain amount of times?

Tags: java, recursion, processing

I need to generate random numbers as an output for a function called randomize. I am trying to generate numbers in the range 0 to 4. However,

- Once 0 is generated 2 times, stop generating 0, `blankCount` counts 0 generations
- Once 1 is generates 4 times, stop generating 1, `birdCount` counts 1 generations
- Once 2 is generated 1 time, stop generating 2, `specialCount` counts 2 generations
- Once 3 is generated 2 times, stop generating 3, `nullCount` counts 3 generations
- Once 4 is generated 1 time, stop generating 4, `crashCount` counts 4 generations

I am setting a place in an array to the output of this function. The function is at the end of the post.
The problem is to get the function to stop calling itself. I get a Stack Overflow Error with this code.

The goal is to have Two 0s, Four 1s, One 2, Two 3s, and One 4

> 0,0,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,4

Can anyone help make this function work?

```
int blankCount = 0;
int birdCount = 0;
int specialCount = 0;
int nullCount = 0;
int crashCount = 0;

int randomize(){
  int num = 0;
  int randomNum = floor(random(0,5));
  
  if(randomNum == 0 && blankCount <= 1) {
    blankCount++;
    num = randomNum;
  }else if(randomNum == 0 && blankCount == 2){
    num = randomize();
  }else if(randomNum == 1 && birdCount <= 3){
    birdCount++;
    num = randomNum;
  }else if(randomNum == 1 && birdCount == 4){
    num = randomize();
  }else if(randomNum == 2 && specialCount <= 0){
    specialCount++;
    num = randomNum;
  }else if(randomNum == 2 && specialCount == 1){
    num = randomize();
  }else if(randomNum == 3 && nullCount <= 1){
    nullCount++;
    num = randomNum;
  }else if(randomNum == 3 && nullCount == 2){
    num = randomize();
  }else if(randomNum == 4 && crashCount <= 0){
    crashCount++;
    num = randomNum;
  }else if(randomNum == 4 && crashCount == 1){
    num = randomize();
  }else{
    print("H ");
  }
  return num;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make a list containing every item that you can legally return.

Then, shuffle it.

Then, to generate a random number, just consume the next item from your shuffled list. Voila - now if you never want more than 4x a `1`, make sure only at most 4 `1` values are in your original list.

I have no idea what your `random(0, 5)` does, but using that to generate random numbers sounds like it's broken by design (pigeon hole principle) - java has a Random class with a much nicer API that isn't broken, by all means use that.

```
class Randomizer {
    private static final List<Integer> INPUTS = List.of(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4);

    private final List<Integer> list;
    private int pos = 0;

    public Randomizer() {
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>(INPUTS);
        Collections.shuffle(list);
    }

    public int next() {
        return list.get(pos++);
    }
}
```

NB: The above will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` once you 'run out' of random numbers. If you want other behaviour, code that in. For example, if you want the algorithm to start over (re-return 0/0/1/1/1/1/2/3/3/4 in random order, re-fresh the order), then you could do, say:

```
public int next() {
    if (pos == list.size()) {
        Collections.shuffle(list); // reshuffle
        pos = 0;
    }
    return list.get(pos++);
}
```

Comment: Actually, the random() function they are using ([Processing's random() function](https://processing.org/reference/random_.html)) is already using java's Random class.

Comment: @Kamakura I looked into it, it is indeed broken. Probably not enough to matter for processing's usual target audience, but if you're writing, say, a poker site, this can bite you in the behind. There are X billion numbers that Math.random() can generate, and if you want to distill that down to 3 separate choices, that is not possible 'uniformly' unless 3 divides perfectly into X billion. Search for 'pigeon hole principle' for more on why it is slightly broken. random's .nextInt(x) is the right call. not any take on float-add-and-round.